# Reading a spark data frame as an array type from Postgres DB

Tags: apache-spark

I have a local PSQL database on my computer. Some columns have the data contained in them as an array. (Example below)

```
+--------------------+
|            _authors|
+--------------------+
|[u'Miller, Roger ...|
|[u'Noyes, H.Pierre']|
|[u'Berman, S.M.',...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 3 rows

root
 |-- _authors: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to read them as an Array / Wrapped array. How do i achieve that?

```
val sqlContext: SQLContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df_records = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname")
  .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
  .option("dbtable", "public.records")
  .option("user", "name")
  .option("password", "pwd").load().select("_authors")
df_records.printSchema()
```

I need to explode this array / flatten in later stages of my pipeline.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried adding `.schema(s: StructType)` to the reader? You must pass the full schema as a StructType object

Comment: @DanieldePaula I could not find any examples. Could you please elaborate?.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two suggestions for you problem:

1) I'm not sure it works for arrays, but it's worth a try: It's possible to define a specific schema when reading a dataframe from a source. Example:

```
val customSchema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("_authors",  DataTypes.createArrayType(StringType), true),
  StructField("int_column", IntegerType, true),
  // other columns...
))

val df_records = sqlContext.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname")
  .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
  .option("dbtable", "public.records")
  .option("user", "name")
  .option("password", "pwd")
  .schema(customSchema)
  .load()

df_records.select("_authors").show()
```

2) If the other option doesn't work, at the moment I can only think of defining a parsing UDF:

```
val splitString: (String => Seq[String]) = { s => 
  val seq = s.split(",").map(i => i.trim).toSeq 

  // Remove "u[" from the first element and "]" from the last:
  Seq(seq(0).drop(2)) ++ 
    seq.drop(1).take(seq.length-2) ++ 
      Seq(seq.last.take(seq.last.length-1))
}

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val newDF = df_records
  .withColumn("authors_array", udf(splitString).apply(col("_authors")))
```

---

- For more details about StructType: [org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)
- For more examples of defining UDFs: [this tutorial](http://www.sparktutorials.net/using-sparksql-udfs-to-create-date-times-in-spark-1.5)

Comment: For custom schema, I'm getting: "jdbc does not allow user-specified schemas.;"